# Run two functions at the same time

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have two functions. How would i run two functions at the same time? I Know should use threading.
I need a example for Multi Threading . I am using Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [_beginthread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx)

```
void CalculatePrimes(void*)
{
  // Do something
}

void TransmitFile(void*)
{
  // Do domething
}

int main()
{
  uintptr_ x = _beginthread(CalculatePrices,0,NULL);
  uintptr_ y = _beginthread(TransmitFile,0,NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

If you've got access to C++11 you can use [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) :

```
void CalculatePrimes()
{
  // Do something
}

void TransmitFile()
{
  // Do domething
}

int main()
{
  std::thread x(CalculatePrices);
  std::thread y(TransmitFile);

  // Both function are now running an different thread
  // We need to wait for them to finish

  x.join();
  y.join();

  return 0;
}
```

And, if you want to get down to the metal you can use the [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) api :

```
DWORD WINAPI CalculatePrimes(void *)
{
  // Do something
  return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI TransmitFile(void *)
{
  // Do something
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  HANDLE x=::CreateThread(NULL,0,CalculatePrimes,NULL,0,NULL);
  HANDLE y=::CreateThread(NULL,0,CalculatePrimes,NULL,0,NULL);

  // Wait for them to finish
  ::WaitForSingleObject(x,INFINITE);
  ::WaitForSingleObject(y,INFINITE);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The MSDN reference for < thread > only goes back to VS2012,not VS2010. You could update to VS2012 (you also need to be running Win 7 or Win 8) Here is a link to a zip of a windows console program written in C that copies a file using two threads, creating a thread to do the writes. It uses windows mutexes and semaphores to implement an inter-thread single linked list messaging interface.

[mtcopy.zip](http://rcgldr.net/misc/mtcopy.zip)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MFC, you could use `AfxBeginThread` to create a `CWinThread`:

```
UINT SomeFunction(LPVOID pParam)
{
    CSomeObject * pObject = (CSomeObject*)pParam;

    // do stuff

    return 0;   // thread completed successfully
}

int main()
{
    CSomeObject pObject = new CSomeObject;
    AfxBeginThread(SomeFunction, pObject);

    ...

    return 0;
}
```

For more information, see [MSDN for AfxBeginThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3w9x78e.aspx).

Comment: You need to be writing an MFC application to call `AfxBeginThread`

Comment: @Sean true, I mistakenly assumed that was the case when I read "using Visual Studio 2010".  Edited the answer to mention MFC.